# Saber menor numero com a Função min()

Tags: python, python-3.x

Pretendo saber qual o menor número desta lista, que abaixo apresento o código.

Não sei onde me estou a enganar, penso que me falta converter a lista.

Exemplo:

```
lista=[1, 3, 5]
def min(values):
    smallest = None
    for value in values:
        if smallest is None or values < smallest:
           smallest = value
    return smallest

menorvalor=min(lista)
```

o erro que me dá é este

> TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'list' and 'int'

Comment: corrija **value** < smallest

Comment: `values < smallest` - não deveria ser `value < smallest`? (`value` no singular ao invés de `values` no plural)

Answer (score 5):

O problema é que você está comparando a lista `values` e não o valor individual `value`.

Errado:

```
if smallest is None or values < smallest:
#                           ^^^ Essa é sua lista, e não o valor iterado
```

Corrigido:

```
if smallest is None or value < smallest:
#                          ^ Aqui estamos comparando um por um
```

Ficando:

```
lista=[1, 3, 5]
def min(values):
    smallest = None
    for value in values:
        if smallest is None or value < smallest:
           smallest = value
    return smallest

menorvalor=min(lista)
```

Veja funcionando no **[IDEONE](https://ideone.com/9L0xxe)**, com uma lista mais "embaralhada" para evidenciar o teste.

Para entender melhor

A linha `for value in values:` "diz" mais ou menos o isso:"Para cada ítem em `values`, execute o código indentado a seguir, com o ítem respectivo na variável `value` a cada iteração (cada uma das execuções)"